# What does 'triumphs' mean in Bacon's essay?

Tags: meaning

> But I cannot tell; this same truth is a naked and open day-light, that
>   doth not show the masks and mummeries and **triumphs** of the world,
>   half so stately and daintily as candle-lights.
>
> "Of Truth" by Francis Bacon (1561–1626) from [Bartleby](http://www.bartleby.com/3/1/1.html)

The word 'triumph' usually means victory, or a state of being victorious. Websites like Oxford-Dictionary and Merriam-Webster more or less show the same explanation. However, I felt it much farfetched to understand it as 'victory' in this context (Of Truth);

The reasons are:

1. Victory is an abstract noun, while its parallel words masks and
   mummeries are concrete;
2. Triumph's meaning should be as close as both
   'masks' and 'mummeries'; It might be best to interpreted as a kind
   of 'ceremony' or 'show';

This is just my guessing, and I am not able to find any proof to it. I don't have OED at hand, and if someone who has the access can show me the relevant entry, that will be of much help.

Comment: In ancient Rome, a triumph was a parade of a victorious general and his legions into the City, ending with sacrifices and ceremonies of thanksgiving.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_triumph,

Comment: Great. Thanks @tautophile! But how come this explanation was not recorded in modern English dictionaries? Perhaps too old to safely be forgotten by us :)

Comment: Strange, David Hwang.  If you Google "triumph definition", the reference to the Roman ceremony comes up.  Same with Merriam-Webster's site, Collins's site, and others, I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, I saw it is in Merriam-Webster's site now, perhaps I missed that before. Google search firstly relates this meaning to its verb. Anyway, this doubt has been cleared up. Thanks tautophile.

Comment: When you’re not able to find any proof to it where did you look, please? Sorry and you’re making a very simple thing too complicated.
Exactly as it “usually” does,  the word “triumph” here means victory - and as elsewhere, it does not mean “the state of being victorious…” that would be “triumphant”, which is as much different in meaning as it is similar in root.
“Victory” is an abstract noun, almost exactly equivalent to “triumph”
I have no idea what its “parallel words masks and mummeries” might mean, concrete or otherwise. Can you explain, our may we drop that?

More…

Comment: Further… What on Earth makes you think “Triumph's meaning” should be “as close as both masks and mummeries”, please? The point there is that “as close” negates anything else. Try it; you can’t re-phrase a sentence that really has that meaning.
Yes, “a triumph” will often be interpreted as a kind of “ceremony” or “show” and if that’s what your Question’s about, please consult at least six on-line dictionaries and then take any remaining doubts to English Language Learners, whose members will queue up to help you.